# how to know user clicked first item of rating bar

Tags: android, ratingbar

I am using android rating bar, consider the current rating is one, when user clicks on first star, I want to set rating as zero. Anyone help me. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subtract one from the `RatingBar` value. Note that this will mean that a zero-star value would be -1, as `RatingBar` starts at 0. If you truly want to consider both zero stars and one star to be the same thing, that's your call.

Comment: Thank you, but how can I know user clicked on first star only?

Comment: @SanyasiraoMopada: The `RatingBar` will return `1`. If you want to distinguish between zero stars and one star, either do not subtract one, or settle for zero stars being `-1`.

Comment: Thank you, but the rating bar returning value only if progress changes, as previous rating 1, and user trying to click on first start, it's not returning any value..

Comment: @SanyasiraoMopada: You get the rating by [calling `getRating()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RatingBar.html#getRating%28%29).